# Returning boolean as an out parameter from stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Is this a valid way to return a boolean as an output parameter from the store procedure? To return true if everything went OK or raise an exception when an error occurred.

```
PROCEDURE STUFF (VAL1 IN NUMBER, VAL2 IN NUMBER, RESULT OUT BOOLEAN)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (A_COLUMN) VALUES (VAL1);
    INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (B_COLUMN) VALUES (VAL2);
    COMMIT;
    RESULT := TRUE;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
//Do stuff;
RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: If you need to know the outcome true/false, why not use as a function? If you are planning to use this procedure/function somewhere in java/c# or etc, boolean doesn't work. Make a wrapper, where it transforms boolean as a varchar Y/N, or number 0/1.

Answer (score 3):

Should be fine if you use it properly. Also, it is a good practice to use `%TYPE` for parameters that refer to columns.

```
DECLARE 
    v_result BOOLEAN; 
    PROCEDURE Stuff (val1   IN table_1.a_column%TYPE, 
                     val2   IN table_2.b_column%TYPE, 
                     result OUT BOOLEAN) 
    IS 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO table_1 (a_column) VALUES (val1); 
        INSERT INTO table_2 (b_column) VALUES (val2); 

        COMMIT; 

        result := TRUE; 
    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                 ROLLBACK; 

                 --Do stuff; 
                 RAISE; 
    END; 
BEGIN 
    Stuff(1, 2, v_result); 

    IF v_result THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('SUCCESS'); 
    -- Do other stuff 
    END IF; 
END; 

/ 

SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take it a step further and suggest that you do *not* "hide" an exception and then return instead a status code, whether it be integer, string or boolean.

Instead, rely on the default error propagation flow of PL/SQL and document exceptions that could be raised in your program.